# Laravel Stripe - Your request was in live mode, but used a known test card

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

This is a strange issue no idea from Laravel or from Stripe?

Used same card to checkout order -- Success payment

Defined Laravel Schedule job to re-order -- (Run command from CLI `php artisan runReorder`) -- Success payment

The scheduled job which runs at 00:00 once a day defined in `Kernel.php`

```
 $schedule->command('runReorder')->dailyAt('00:00');
```

Failed payment and got the following error:

> Your card was declined. Your request was in live mode,
> but used a known test card

in Advance cache and configs are cleared
Merchant account is on `LIVE` mode

Comment: Are you using the same card for the schedule?? or a different one, because the error is pretty much clear that you are using test card in live environment

Comment: I used the same card for all processes and it failed on auto scheduled job.

Comment: Try this process again in the sandbox to check if you are facing it or not, might be related to the Live environment and schedule complications.

Comment: My guess is your scheduled job is using your live API key, where as your original payment attempts were made with your test API key. If you're using test cards, then you can only use them with your test API key as the error suggests.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmer LIVE credential stored in ENV and merchant account is on LIVE

Comment: @JonathanSteele nana I just run the same command on CLI system/stripe will charge the amount successfully.

Comment: If you're making API requests with your live keys then, as the error states, you're clearly using credentials for one of the Stripe [test cards](https://stripe.com/docs/testing). They don't work in test mode. Equally you should not be processing test transactions with your live API keys.